# Ubuntu Studio Launch Sub-menus Don't Show Up

Tags: launcher, menu

I installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 over my Linux Mint 21.1 Vera installation on a Windows dual boot system. I am a pro musician but new to Linux. The start/launch menu is not working properly because sub-category menu items are not showing up under main categories like Audio Production, Graphic Design, and Video Production.

Sub-menu items not showing up in start/launch menu:

[image: Sub-menu items not showing up in start/launch menu]

When I open the Menu Editor, I see that all the proper sub-category menu items are there with the associated program launchers in the right-hand Menu Editor pane, but if I open any of the main categories like Audio Production in *Edit Desktop File*, the text is in a foreign language (I think Latin).

Menu main category text files are in a foreign language:

[image: Menu main category text files are in a foreign language]

Any ideas about how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated. This problem makes it hard to find associated programs.

Comment: The documentation clearly states Ubuntu Studio Installer will not work on a Linux Mint system, so if this what you did the results are not expected to work. Linux Mint is not a Ubuntu system (*just Ubuntu based*) and is off-topic here.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: I am so new to Linux that I do not know the difference between Ubuntu based and official flavors. I did not find anything in the documentation about Mint and System Information for my computer said "Linux Mint 21.1 Vera base: Ubuntu 22.04." I will wipe the partition and reinstall. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu all come from ubuntu.com You aren't using a Ubuntu system, but a Ubuntu-based system with changes. As Linux Mint *devs* don't have the resources to create/build everything themselves, they rely on Ubuntu packages they don't control; thus use an extra layer of software to *hack* around this (runtime *adjustments*), which means things can fail to work on Mint that are good with Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu. A *dev* of Ubuntu Studio hoped it would work on Linux Mint, alas when it didn't - he blogged about it, but that it worked on all Ubuntu *flavors*.

Comment: Just FYI  (*and off-topic*), but the same *dev* I mentioned also ensures it works on Fedora ([*Fedora Jam*](https://labs.fedoraproject.org/en/jam/))  ... but that's off-topic here; just as Linux Mint is (neither is Ubuntu)  ... *I've left this comment only as FYI for OP, with assumption it'll be closed & deleted due to off-topic subject*